# Bus stop on the left side of the road

Tags: sumo, traffic-simulation

I am fairly new to SUMO, and I have been creating bus stops, however I am only able to get bus stops on the right side of the edge.  Is it possible to create island platforms (Center Platform) in SUMO?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the lane where the vehicle should stop when defining the bus stop

```
<busStop id="my_bus_stop" lane="edge_2" endPos="100"/>
```

will place the stop on the third lane (index 2) of edge `edge`. See https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Simulation/Public_Transport.html

Comment: Thank you, but I don't seem to make it work.  When I create an edge, all lanes have the same direction, which means that if I have a central platform in a 2 lane edge and it is in lane="edge_1" it would certainly be in between lanes, but both lanes would be facing the same direction, meaning it would be on the right of one lane and on the left on another lane.  I'm trying to have one lane facing one direction, and another lane facing the opposite direction, with the platform being on the left of both lanes at the same time.

Comment: Currently you cannot have a busstop on the left side of the road. Is it ust for the visual appearance or is there some simlation property you are aiming at?

Comment: A little bit of both, for the simulation property having a central platform reduces the time a person in the simulation need to spend to move from one direction to another or change routes more efficiently.

Comment: I think you depend on the implementation of https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/issues/5115 then

Answer (score 0):

To model correct access times with the current placment limitations, you can define length="0" for the access elements that connects busstops with the opposide-direction sidewalk: https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Simulation/Public_Transport.html#access_lanes